# Jquery datepicker error in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, safari, datepicker

In my js im trying to load date from db and save it into jquery datepicker, it works fine in chrome and firefox, but shows error as null is **not an object(evaluvating c.contains)**  my date picker is intitalised before the set date , my code is:

```
 if(typeof res.dob !== "undefined" && typeof res.dob !== "" && typeof res.dob !== null){
    $(BasicInfo.elements.dob).datepicker('setDate', res.dob);
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but `typeof` will never return an empty string or null, there's no need for all those checks.

Comment: What version of Safari? I suspect you're using an old version that's not supported.

Comment: See https://jqueryui.com/browser-support/

Comment: safari version 10.1, but i tried to fix it with manually showing the datepicker, then call the sateDate, and hide datepicker, and everything works fine, and no error. Is there any other way to fix this? like a proper method?

Comment: Something internal to jQuery-UI is setting `c` to `null` when it should be an array or string. Only the jQuery programmers could tell what's going on. But they won't bother with such an old browser.

Comment: This isn't an issue with your code, it's a jQuery-UI compatibility issue.